# Relational override symbol

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

Looking for a way to write the following infix binary operator, meaning "relational override":

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're lucky: the minus sign and `\vartriangleleft` have the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\reloverrideleft}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rel@override\vartriangleleft}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\reloverrideright}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rel@override\vartriangleright}}

\newcommand{\rel@override}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1-$\cr$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \reloverrideleft B_{\reloverrideleft}$

$A \reloverrideright B_{\reloverrideright}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With other math fonts it may not work flawlessly, I'm afraid.

For `acmart` we need to clip the minus sign:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\reloverrideleft}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rel@override\vartriangleleft}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\reloverrideright}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rel@override\vartriangleright}}

\newcommand{\rel@override}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\clipbox*{{0.17\width} 0 {0.83\width} {\height}}{$\m@th#1-$}\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1#2$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \reloverrideleft B_{\reloverrideleft}$

$A \reloverrideright B_{\reloverrideright}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm using [acmart.cls](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acmart?lang=en), and it took me a while to figure out that I have to *not* import `amssymb` for this to render nicely (if I import `amssymb` the minus sign is too short).

Comment: @Roly With `acmart` the minus sign is a bit too long, unfortunately.

Comment: @Roly There's a reason why a mwe is _always_ needed!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Hah, yeah. I was trying to be cute with the Detexify "spec".

Comment: @Roly Detexify is a great tool, indeed!

Answer (score 21):

Package `stix` has it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$a\dsub b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually `texdoc comprehensive` is a very good source for information like this.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the answer above, but this is also useful.